# Creating an iOS UPnP App

Tags: ios, streaming, upnp, dlna

I'm working on an app that needs to be able to stream videos, music and photos to other devices such as chromecast, games consoles etc.. over wifi.

I have looked around and found libraries that support this but are not much help in terms of tutorials and getting it running on iOS. i'm using ARC Xcode 5 targeting iOS 7+

If anybody has guides, tutorials or source code to help me achieve this it would be much appreciated.